# SharePoint 2013 Admin Content DB is corrupted - Recover/Fix options?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

After recovering from a recent hardware failure on our SharePoint server (single server farm), all the SQL DBs were in suspect mode, to change the mode back to normal, we ran the consistency checks on all DBs and successfully changed back to normal mode. However, one particular database i.e. SharePoint_AdminContent_ is still causing SQL crashes with messages like:

The Database ID 6, Page (1:11812), slot 22 for LOB data type node does not exist. This is usually caused by transactions that can read uncommitted data on a data page. Run DBCC CHECKTABLE.

dbcc checkdb with REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS fails and does not complete successfully.

I have set the DB to single user mode for now, the central admin works when I set to multi user mode but the SQL logs very quickly fill up the hard drive with crash dumps. I suspect that the hardware failure has caused some serious damage to the DB which cannot be repaired.

I tried to move central admin site to a new content db using move-spsite but it fails with the error given above.

Now, in an attempt to repair central admin, I have tried to unprovision the central admin and tried to re-create the central admin using both Configuration Wizard GUI and PowerShell, one by one but both these methods return the same error that I have specified above, while trying to create new central admin.

I have tried to backup the corrupted DB and restore it to a new DB to see if it works, but it does not. The corruption transfers to restored DB as well.

I have also tried to detach the corrupted AdminContent DB from SQL and then tried to create a new central admin site (hoping that it will create a new admin content DB) but it complains that it cannot find the old admin content db (I suppose SharePoint_Config DB holds the references to old AdminContent DB), anyways this method fails as well because the old DB detached, and is not available.

Then, I have tried to create a new content database under central admin web application, unprovisioned central admin site, removed corrupted AdminContent DB (through central admin) and tried to create new central admin site using psconfiggui, it did not open the site until I attached corrupted admin content DB through powershell (mount-spcontentdatabase)

I have a full farm backup taken using SharePoint native tools through powershell. It has central admin backup but it cannot be restored individually, I will need to restore the whole farm somewhere to even try to see if restored admin content DB will work and even if it works, how would I transfer it back to original farm because it will have a new guid and how would I associate it with original farm? I cannot restore it to original farm because the backup is 3-4 days older and I can only restore admincontent if I perform a full farm restore which will overwrite all the content as well.

Is there any way I can setup a new Admin Content DB and create a new central admin site using that DB? or anything I can do to fix this? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After 7 months you probably fixed it, on that case please share your approach with us, otherwise let me recommend you to have a look on:
http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/finding-table-name-page-id/

Particularly on this clause and how to read its output:

```
DBCC PAGE (6, 1, 11812, 0) WITH TABLERESULTS;
```

Note: The article's author is Paul Randal.